# How to remotely retrieve a java thread dump

Tags: java, jmx

JVisualVM connects to a Java process over JMX and can produce a thread dump through the click of a button. I'd like to add a similar feature to my own application so that it can request thread dumps from remote services.

Which MBeans do I need to interrogate to get this information? and how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use MBean with name `"java.lang:type=Threading"`. It's interface is described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html).

In order to get thread dump you first need to use `getAllThreadIds` method and then loop through all retrieved ids and call `getThreadInfo` method for each of them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [ThreadMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) management interface.

This [FullThreadDump](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ThisFullThreadDumpclassdemonstratesthecapabilitytogetafullthreaddumpandalsodetectdeadlockremotely.htm) class demonstrates the capability to get a full thread dump and also detect deadlock remotely using JMX.